# (Tcl/Tk) How to change checkbutton configurations

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I need two checkbuttons, and when 'op.invariants' is unchecked the 'op.belief' must be disabled. And when 'op.belief' is checked, check 'ob.invariants' automatically

follow the code:

```
checkbutton $op.invariants -text "Find Invariant Violations" -variable mcFindInvViolations -onvalue true -offvalue false \
    -command { if { !$mcFindInvViolations } { set st_abr "disabled";  $op.belief configure -state disabled } else { set st_abr "normal"; $op.belief configure -state normal } }

checkbutton $op.belief -text "Apply Belief Revision" -variable mcApplyBeliefRevision -onvalue true -offvalue false -state $st_abr \
    -command { if { $mcApplyBeliefRevision } { $op.invariants select } }
```

But when i execute it, result in this error:
can't read 'op': no such variable

the checkbutton is named with a variable, but it is not acessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you've got is that you're running this code inside a procedure (sensibly!) and yet the callback scripts are being evaluated at the global level; these are not closures, they're just plain old scripts.

The fix is to put callback code into procedures that take the `op` value as an argument:

```
proc updatedInvariants {op} {
    global mcFindInvViolations st_abr; # List out variables as needed
    if { !$mcFindInvViolations } {
        set st_abr "disabled"
        $op.belief configure -state disabled
    } else {
        set st_abr "normal"
        $op.belief configure -state normal
    }
}
proc updateBelief {op} {
    global mcApplyBeliefRevision
    if { $mcApplyBeliefRevision } {
        $op.invariants select
    }
}
```

The, you construct the code to use these callbacks such that you bind the value of `op` to them. This is easy with the `list` command:

```
checkbutton $op.invariants -text "Find Invariant Violations" -variable mcFindInvViolations -onvalue true -offvalue false \
    -command [list updatedInvariants $op]
checkbutton $op.belief -text "Apply Belief Revision" -variable mcApplyBeliefRevision -onvalue true -offvalue false -state $st_abr \
    -command [list updatedBelief $op]
```

Note that this works even if `op` contains all sorts of weird characters; the `list` will just do whatever quoting is necessary.